# Adding specific 3rd and 4th columns in shell scripting and need to get complete output

Tags: shell, scripting

I have extracted a data file in the format below:

```
MRFRS0004,2019-04-30,610,610
MRFRS0004,2019-05-01,13,13
MRFRS0004,2019-05-01,3,3
MRFRS0004,2019-05-01,1012,1012
AMTRT68,2019-04-30,4341,0
AMTRT68,2019-04-30,495,495
AMTRT68,2019-04-30,142904,142904
AMTRT68,2019-04-30,447,447
RAMBBRAO,2019-04-30,4609,4609
RAMBBRAO,2019-05-01,3788,0
RAMBBRAO,2019-05-01,585,585
RAMBBRAO,2019-05-01,4609,4609
```

I need output like:

```
MRFRS0004 2019-04-30    1028    1028
AMTRT68   2019-04-30    148187  143846
RAMBBRAO  2019-04-30    13591   9803
```

We have tried with few awk commands but are not getting the complete output:

```
awk '{arr[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in arr) {print i,arr[i]}}' $FILENAME
```

```
awk -F\" '{s += $3} {o += $4} END{print $1 ,$2 $3 $4 }' logtwo.txt
```

Comment: source file is comma separated and even my output file also comma separated also not a problem but it should add 3rd and 4th column values of particular node and need to provide output like below

Comment: MRFRS0004, 2019-04-30,1028,1028
AMTRT68,2019-04-30,148187,143846
RAMBBRAO,2019-04-30,13591,13591     it is showing here as single line but it will be line by line